# Mouseless Navigation in Safari with Cmd+F on Mac

Tags: macos, browser, safari, navigation

how to choose highlighted search results from the (cmd+F) word search? I know that I can change from one to the next one with "Tab" button. Pressing the "Enter" button on the highlighted word (in order to open that new link as I did on my Windows, but it does not work on my Mac). I always have to use my mouse in order to open/click on it. Is there another way to choose? I want to navigate faster through Safari.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to navigate faster through Safari, you can use a plugin/extension called 'Gleebox'. It's very useful for selecting links simply by pressing a shortcut (which you can set to whatever you like) and then typing the word. It will highlight it in green and you can press enter to select it. You can also press tab to move from item to item. It can also help you select just headers, image links, etc.

Gleebox for Safari is experimental however. Using Chrome, it can be downloaded here: https://glee.github.io/

Comment: Hey, thanks for finally answering my answer. Actually my issue was still unsolved and I checked out your recommendation its a convenient Add On for the Google Chrome Browser, even though its not being developed and enhanced anymore; for all people looking for something more sophisticated Add On which allows to navigate through the web only with the keyboard, I can highly recommend to try out the often updated option called Vimium, its open source and can be downloaded here on GitHub under the following link: https://vimium.github.io

Comment: Yep, the only problem with vimium is that it doesn't play nice with other extensions. https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/2542#issuecomment-309307049

Another option like vimium is called surfkeys (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/surfingkeys/gfbliohnnapiefjpjlpjnehglfpaknnc). The only problem is that for me, it takes up 100% CPU. See here: https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys/issues/388#issuecomment-309470089

Comment: Btw. just found yesterday. There is a Vimium extension for Safari as well. Its called Vimari, you can find it here: https://github.com/guyht/vimari